# How to obtain a lower mass bound for a unstable (or stable) particle from Poisson statistics?

Tags: particle-physics, statistics

Imagine you have a particle (stable e.g. if some R-symmetry or similar does exits) heavy or not so heavy...

Question: how to guess a lower (upper bound as well) with the aid of Poisson statistics, the observation (or unobservation!) of some event involving such a particle? It is necessary to know the theoretical expection of the number of event in order to get the mass lower bound? Would the exponential distribution serve as well?

Remark: the experiment counts only the number of (observed if any) particles.

Comment: What do you have statistics on? Reaction rates (e.g. cross section, yield)?

Comment: Number of events, likely low statistics, and due to that you have Poisson and not-normal distribution...